# Is there any way keep the element after stack.pop()?

Tags: java, stack

I know the main idea of pop is to get and delete the top element. But how about if I calculate the sum of the stack by method pop(), and I still need those element in the code later? I know I can use peek() to get the top element and I don't know how to get other element.

Here is the `sum` method I want to adapt:

```
public int sum(){
    int sum = 0;
    int n = super.size();
    int i;
    for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        int s = (Integer)super.pop();
        sum = sum + s;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

### Edit

The class type extends another type named `LinkedStack`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedStack {

    protected ChainNode top;
    protected int size;

    public boolean empty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public Object peek() {
        if (empty())
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        return top.element;
    }


    public void push(Object theElement) {
        // put theElement at the top of the stack
        top = new ChainNode(theElement, top);
        size++;
    }

    public Object pop() {
        if (empty())
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        Object topElement = top.element;
        top = top.next;
        size--;
        return topElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your constraints ? If memory is not the issue, you can copy the stack to a collection / list and then iterate over it .

Comment: Are you extending the `java.util.Stack` class? Please provide all the relevant code.

Comment: A `Stack` is still a `Collection`, so you can use any loops you like (like `for(Integer i: this) { ... }`).

Comment: Thanks @Sigma, but still you haven't afforded the whole implementation. What's the extended type? Are you forced to use the `pop` method?

Comment: @tmarouane I am forced to use the method in class linkedstack, in the main code will be like s.push(new integer 123) and so on.  I also updated my original code which calculate the sum but will delete the whole stack

Comment: @Sigma, please post your ChainNode code. In addition, by super I assume you are extending your own LinkedStack class, which is probably not needed

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pop elements from stack to find sum. You only need to iterate in order to calculate that sum. Stream Api is very useful here also

Check the following example

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);
stack.push(4);
    
Integer sum = stack.stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

**Edit**

After more explanation from comments here is how a method which would take a stack as parameter would return the sum.

```
public static Integer calculateSum(Stack<Integer> stack){
        int sum = 0;
        for(Integer element: stack){
            sum += element;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: why? It is already there for you from JDK

Comment: Sorry and thank you for help! but It is a exercise which require a sum method in a linked stack. I am still learning java and have to write a sum method to fulfill the requirement .

Comment: for a generic stack, instead of Java stack, you need to pop each element and save them in a mirror stack while doing sum. After which, pop from the mirror and reconstruct the original

Comment: @Boug It is useful, thx a lot ! but I am trying write a method without argument like sum(), though I really learn a lot from your code .

Comment: @Bing Wang can I create a mirror stack in the method sum()?

Comment: @Sigma you can do anywhere. Sure you can do that in the sum() if it is a class method. You can also cheat by update sum in push/pop and achieve O(1) speed (which is not recommended when just learning algorithm)

Comment: @BingWang I tried to create stack s = new stack(); and super,pop() try to store the value in the t first with a for loop, but the code only store one top element, other element is fail to push in t. Can you give me some example or website so that I can understand and get more know about it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending the `java.util.Stack` collection type, you can use the default `Iterator` or the iterate over the `Stack` directly using a `for each` syntax as it extends the `Iterable` super-interface:

```
public class CustomStack<T> extends Stack<T> {

    public void printElements() {
        for (T element : this) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this `Stack` extension:

```
CustomStack<Integer> stack = new CustomStack<>();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);
stack.printElements(); // prints: 1, 2 and 3

System.out.println(stack.size()); // prints 3 as the Stack elements are un-changed
```

### Sum sample:

Here down the updated type `CustomStack` to show a `#sum` method:

```
public class CustomStack<T extends Integer> extends Stack<T> {

    public int sum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (T element : this) {
            sum = sum + (int) element;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

CustomStack<Integer> stack = new CustomStack<>();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);

System.out.println(stack.sum()); // will print 6
System.out.println(stack.size()); // prints 3 as the elements are still un-changed
```

Comment: I think your answer does not directly address what OP asked for, though he should be able to take the ideas

Comment: Yes still it doesn't address the `#pop` method usage case but provides an alternative if viable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `pop()` as it is you could invoke it over a `clone` version of your data structure. On original `DS` you'll have always unmodified data and with `clone-DS` you could invoke what ever methods wanted, which would modify(or not) data. Simple iteration over initial DS is better over cloning for this case, but for different scenarios maybe clone will fit better.